# How to extract the upper values from the whole 3D array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Is it possible to extract the upper values from the whole  3D array?
A simple example of a 3D array is below:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[[7, 4, 2], [5, 0, 4], [0, 0, 5]],
               [[7, 6, 1], [3, 9, 5], [0, 8, 7]],
               [[8, 10, 3], [1, 2, 15], [9, 0, 1]]])
```

Comment: What do you mean by upper values?

Comment: elements of the matrix above the diagonal

Comment: @Noor Could you show us the desired output?

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the numpy [building-matrices](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/routines.array-creation.html#building-matrices) functions like [numpy.triu](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.triu.html#numpy.triu) (triangle-upper)  or [numpy.tril](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.tril.html#numpy.tril) (triangle-lower)  to return a copy of a matrix with the elements above or below the k-th diagonal zeroed.

If, on the other hand, you are only interested in the values ​​above or below the diagonal (without having a copy of the matrix), you can simply use [numpy.triu_indices](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.triu_indices.html) and [numpy.tril_indices](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tril_indices.html), as follows:

```
upper_index = np.triu_indices(n=3, k=1)
```

where `n` is the size of the arrays for which the returned indices will be valid, and `k` the diagonal offset.

and return the indices for the triangle. The returned tuple contains two arrays, each with the indices along one dimension of the array:

```
(array([0, 0, 1], dtype=int64), array([1, 2, 2], dtype=int64))
```

now you can use the indexes obtained as indexes of your array and you will get:

```
a[upper_index]
```

and gives:

```
array([[5, 0, 4],
       [0, 0, 5],
       [0, 8, 7]])
```

Similarly you can find the part under the diagonal using `numpy.tril_indices`.

Answer (score 0):

IUUC, You could use [triu_indices](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.triu_indices.html):

```
result = a[np.triu_indices(3)]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[[7 4 2]
 [5 0 4]
 [0 0 5]
 [3 9 5]
 [0 8 7]
 [9 0 1]]
```

If you want those strictly above the diagonal, you can pass an offset value:

```
result = a[np.triu_indices(3, 1)]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[[5 0 4]
 [0 0 5]
 [0 8 7]]
```